# Static variables in java

Tags: java, variables, static, instance-variables

I have scenario like this

```
public class Test{

   static int a;
   int b;

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Test t1  = new Test();
      Test t2 = new Test();

   }
}
```

What will be the variables in object t1 and object t2?

As per my understanding since variable `a` is a static variable it will be both in object 1 and object 2.

And `b` will be created separate copy for both the objects.

But when I assign a value to variable b ie(`int b=1`) and call it like `System.out.println(t1.b)`, `System.out.println(t2.b)`

Instead of getting an error I am getting 1 as output from both the objects.

Why is that?

Answer (score 9):

> As per my understanding since variable a is static variable it will be both in object 1 and object 2.

No. It's not in *either* object. It exists without reference to any particular instance at all. Although Java *allows* you to refer to it "via" a reference, e.g. `int x = t1.a;` you shouldn't do so. You should instead refer to it via the class name (`test.a` in your case - although you should also start following Java naming conventions) to make it clear that it's static.

> And b will be created separate copy for both the objects.

Yes.

> But when I assign a value to variable b ie(`int b=1`) and call it like `System.out.println(t1.b), System.out.println(t2.b)` Instead of getting an error I am getting 1 as output from both the objects.

Well that's because you've basically given it an initial value to assign for each new object. That's entirely reasonable. There are still two independent variables:

```
t1.b = 2;
t2.b = 3;
System.out.println(t1.b); // Prints 2
System.out.println(t2.b); // Prints 3
```

Comment: since b is a local variable it should not be accessible . but i am not getting any error instead i am getting values can you help me with an example

Comment: @prasad: You didn't say that you'd changed it to be a local variable. The code you've shown declares it as a field. I assumed you were just changing `int b;` to `int b = 1;`. If that's not the case, you should edit your question to show the *actual code* that doesn't behave as you expect, rather than describing it vaguely and making us guess what you mean.

Comment: :what variables will be present in t1 and t2 if b is not assigned to 1

Comment: @prasad the value would be 0. It is good practice to initialize the value of your variables in the constructor though.

Comment: @prasad: The same variables would be present (just `b` in each) but with a value of 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 3):

Static variables are class members that are shared among all objects. There is only one copy of them in main memory. Static variables are created at run time on Heap area.

In case of yours...

```
int b = 1;
```

it's an assignment at class level, **making 1 the default value for variable b**(In normal case default value is 0). hence when you print it, its gives you the ans as 1 not error.

```
int b = 1; //initialized b to 1 for all obj of class Test
System.out.println(t1.b); // Prints 1
System.out.println(t2.b); // Prints 1
```

Answer (score 2):

No, a static variable is not an instance variable but a class variable.

That's, every instance of this class shares the same reference of those variables.

Take a look at [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: I generally avoid the "every instance of this class shares..." terminology as that suggests that the instance has some knowledge - or that you need *some* instance to get at the field. I prefer to talk about it not being related to instances *at all*, but instead being related to the type.

Comment: Yes, you're right, because there is no need of an instance to access a class variable

Answer (score 1):

Here a is static variable and b is instance or non-static variable.

For static variable, only one copy is created for all objects, where as for instance variable, one copy is created for each object.
Here when b=1, for every object of that Test class, one copy is created and it can access it through its object name. So output will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that is exactly what it should output. 
If you assign say,

```
int b=1;
```

that assignment is at class level, making 1 the default value for variable b. 
However, if you assign like this:

```
t1.b=1;
```

that will assign 1 to only the copy of variable b in object t1.

Try it.

Comment: what variables will be present in t1 and t2

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables are class variables. `static` variable are stored in static memory.

`static` variables are created to access inside `main()` method.
The `static` variables can be accessed by their class name, if they are present in outside class.

```
class sv {
  static String name = "abc";
}

public class staticvariable {
  static int t;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("static variable is - "+t);
    System.out.println(sv.name);
    t=100;
    System.out.println(t);
  }
}
```