What happens when I have 2 static variables with the same name?
I am a Java beginner and am having trouble understanding the output of the System.out.println(((A)b).s) in the code.
My understanding is that static variables can be changed anywhere in the class and hence I expected to have the value as 2. Upon investigating in the code it seems that I have two values for the static variable s... Why is this happening, shouldn't both refer to the same variable since the name and type is equal?
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class A {
    static int s;
    int o;
    A(int i) { o = i; s = i + 1; 
    System.out.println("A constructor called! String s is:" + s);
    }
    int m(int i) { return i; }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return String.format("A2S: %d %d" , o, s); }
}

class B extends A {
    int o;
    B(int i) { super(i); o = i; }
    @Override
    int m(int i) { return i + s; }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return String.format("B2S: %d %d", o, s); }
}

class C extends A {
    static int s;
    int o;
    C(int i) { super(i); o = i; s = i - 1; 
    System.out.println("C constructor called! String s is:" + s);}
    @Override
    int m(int i) { return i + s; }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return String.format("C2S: %d %d", o, s); }
}

class D extends C {
    int o;
    D(int i) { super(i); o = i; }
    @Override
    int m(int i) { return i + o + s; }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return String.format("D2S: %d %d", o, s); }
}

public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int o = 1;
        B b = new B(7);
        System.out.println(b);
        C c = new C(5);
        System.out.println(c);
        D d = new D(3);
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(((C)d).o);
        System.out.println("This is the s: " + b.s);
        System.out.println("This is the s: " + c.s);
        System.out.println("This is the s: " + d.s);
        System.out.println(((A)b).s);
        System.out.println(((A)d).m(o));
    }
}


They are not the same variable though.

No, A.s and C.s are two separate and distinct declarations.  Side note:  get in the habit of placing exactly one blank line before each constructor declaration and each method declaration.  The mark of a professional programmer is writing code that is easy for others to read and understand.

@talex The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568399/static-variables-in-java is clearly not a duplicate of this one. That question is not about variables with the same name.

@Lii answer to that question explains what static variable is, and how it works.

@talex: But the answers to that other question don't explain the name space issue that arise when two different static variables in a class hierarchy have the same name. That it the subject of this question. So they are not duplicates at all. Please join me and vote to re-open this question to fix your mistake.

The declaration s in A is declaring a different variable to the declaration of s in C.  Yes, they are different variables with the same (simple) name s.
When you use the name s, what it means depends on where you are using it.

In A, the simple name s refers to the same thing as A.s.
In B, the simple name s refers to A.s.  The name has been inherited from the namespace of A.
In C, the simple name s now refers to the s declared in C; i.e. C.s.
In D, the simple name s also refers to C.s which has been inherited from the namespace of C.

Technically speaking, each class defines its own namespaces1.
Technically speaking, the variable s declared in A, is hidden by the s declared in C.  This also applies in D.
This is all specified in the Java Language Specification.
And this is why your code is behaving the way it does.


Why is this happening, shouldn't both refer to the same variable since the name and type is equal?

No.  That is not correct.  Your intuition is not correct.  There are two distinct static variables called s.  Their full names are A.s and C.s.

If you declare 2 variables with the same name in one class, that is a compilation error.

If you declare 2 variables with the same name in different classes, they are different variables.

The above are true irrespective of the types used for the variables, or whether they are static or instance variables.



Note that you can refer to A.s as B.s and C.s as D.s.  But don't do that.  It is bad style to do that, because it is liable to mislead the reader into thinking that (say) B.s is a static variable of B.  It isn't.

In this:
System.out.println(((A)b).s);

you are referring to s with a syntax that makes it appear that s is and instance variable.  In fact this is referring to the static variable A.s.  In fact all of the following will print that variable:
System.out.println(A.s);
System.out.println(B.s);
System.out.println(a.s);  // where `a` is a variable whose type is `A`
System.out.println(b.s);  // where `b` is a variable whose type is `B`
System.out.println(((A) b).s);

But only the first one is good style.  The others are all misleading in one way or another, and should be avoided.

1 - In fact, there are separate distinct namespaces for class names, method names and variable names.  You can declare a field m and a method m in the same class, and they don't collide or hide one another.
